# How to install parsoid in CentOS?

Tags: centos, mediawiki

I am trying to install VisualEditor extension http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor for MediaWiki. A pre-requisite is to install Parsoid service.

The instructions for Parsoid installation does not have any reference for CentOS.

Can anyone give any directions in how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: http://everyday-tech.com/apt-get-on-centos/ + `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install parsoid`?

Comment: And the award for the world must unhelpful comment goes to...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git clone --recursive https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/services/parsoid/deploy
```

That should copy all Parsoid deploy files in your server. You can install some extra packages by doing the following:

```
git clone https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/p/mediawiki/services/parsoid
cd parsoid
npm install
```

Comment: Hi. I'm not using mediawiki anymore, so I won't be able to test this right now. Thanks for answering anyway.